# Chrome extension compiled by Webpack throws `unsafe-eval` error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I get this error when reloading my Chrome Extension after compiling using Webpack:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
    
    
at new Function (<anonymous>)
at evalExpression (compiler.js:33919)
at jitStatements (compiler.js:33937)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._interpretOrJit (compiler.js:34520)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34448)
at compiler.js:34347
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34347)
at compiler.js:34217
at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
```

My CSP grants the `unsafe-eval` permission.

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

How can I permit the use of `eval()` in my code (because Webpack uses this to generate source maps)?

Comment: one way I can avoid this problem is to use `ng build --prod`, but the prod build takes a loooot longer

Comment: Adding `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'` to your Webpack config fixes the issue by overriding the default source mapping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A chrome extension is not allowed to use `unsafe-eval`, or `eval` at all in fact.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy

When making a Chrome extension understand that it's severely limited by Content Security Policies. Make sure you read and understand the WebExtensions Content Security Policy. If you want to have an inline script like:

```
<script>
    alert('hello')
</script>
```

You're gonna have to calculate the script tags contents into its SHA256 value and add that to your manifest in order for it to be allowed to be executed.

Comment: The page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy explicitly states that you CAN `Allow the extension to use eval()` (by using `unsafe-eval`). But that doesn't work for me...

Comment: @manuell This is what I use and it works: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"`

Comment: "A chrome extension is not allowed to use unsafe-eval, or eval at all in fact." I don't think this is correct (anymore). [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval)

Comment: @stackprotector It still works, Just tested it with a Crypto Miner with Manifest V2, Although I'm not sure about V3 if that's even a thing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy at the bottom you can read explicitly that "Note: Valid examples display the correct use of keys in CSP. However, extensions with 'unsafe-eval', remote script, blob, or remote sources in their CSP are not allowed for Firefox extensions as per the add-on policies and due to major security issues." The same applies to Chrome extensions. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/

Comment: So while you guys are correct in that the documentation states that you can allow unsafe-eval for CSP rules, it also states both for Firefox and Chrome extensions if you dig a bit that unsafe-eval is in fact not allowed no matter what you do, because it's a security risk. CSP rules are used primarily for websites and REST api's, that's why the documentation states you can allow unsafe-eval, and why the texts for "doesn't work in extensions" is so small, because extensions are one of the smaller places where CSP rules are used.

Answer (score 156):

Took me a few hours but what you probably want to do is change the style of source mapping webpack uses.
By default it uses eval.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

I added this to my webpack.config.js:

`devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'`

The trick to this was figuring out why `webpack --mode development` has the error and `webpack --mode production` didn't.

Also I'm using React not Polymer but I'm pretty sure this still applies.

Comment: i was getting this error whenever i changed `mode` to `development`, there was no error when using `production`, so i added `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'` and i no longer get the error.  does this line need to be removed when you use `production` mode?  or is it OK to leave it there when in `production` mode? i don't really understand what it does, i just want the error to go away :)

Comment: Surprisingly this did the trick, thanks! Now I will figure it out why. Thanks again.

Comment: If you add `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'` to `webpack.config.js` to get around this issue, do you need to *remove* this setting when running in `production` mode again, or is it only applied when running in `development` mode?

Comment: it took me one minute with your help. thanks!

Comment: If you encounter some libraries that are not defined, remember to set the es version to the latest so that the library code is not populated.

```"@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false, "targets": "last 2 Chrome versions" }```

Comment: This just changed the error to a runtime "DevTools failed to load source map". But it is still better to have no source map than to have no service worker...

Answer (score 33):

Interesting read to overcome via Manifest

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

> Evaluated JavaScript
>
> The policy against eval() and its relatives like
>   setTimeout(String), setInterval(String), and new Function(String) can
>   be relaxed by adding 'unsafe-eval' to your policy:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

> However, we strongly recommend against doing this.
>   These functions are notorious XSS attack vectors.

Comment: Adding my use case to bump in search results: I was trying to use the "webpack-extension-reloader" to automatically reload my webpack-built extension on webpack compile and kept getting OP's error in the chrome://extensions error log for my unpacked extension. Ultimately, this broke the reloader's ability to do its job. Adding this answer's solution to my manifest.json resolved the issue though.

Comment: 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "'unsafe-eval'" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.

Comment: Attention: unsafe evals only works on Chrome manifest v3

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for the answer from @Randy. However, For Vue CLI generated vue project, there's no `webpack.config.js`, so the solution will be adding the following config into `vue.config.js`:

```js
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Randy! Really helpful!

Comment: Didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack V5

Use `--no-devtool` to get out of trouble quickly.

No eval code, no `.map` file.

```
npx webpack watch --no-devtool
```

webpack cli
https://webpack.js.org/api/cli#negated-flags

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I meet this issue because I add `istanbul` plugin in babel.config.js.

And the build result contains `new Function('return this')`

Answer (score 1):

#### For Manifest 3 you can use

```json
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_page":"script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" 
}
```

Comment: For me is working with `extension_pages` instead of `extension_page`.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts from external domains are not allowed in mv3, all scripts must be included into extension package.

Please see the [Migrating to Manifest V3.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/)

Answer (score -2):

In my case working on an MVC 5 application, all I had to do was to install the Nuget package in Visual Studio: 'NWebsec.Mvc' and the application ran just fine.