# Can't import tensorflow.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am developing a chrome extension, where I use my trained keras model. For this I need to import a library `tensorflow.js`. How should I do that?

I tried to import `tensorflow.js` in my project by two ways:

1. in `background.js` by `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';`
2. I downloaded `tf.min.js` and tried to add it in my `manifest.json`

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.1",

  "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js", "tf.min.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","content.js"]
      }
   ]
}
```

In the first case the error was `"unexpected token *";`

and in the second case the error was `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: tf is not defined`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> I downloaded `tf.min.js` and tried to add it in my `manifest.json`

Try putting the `tf.min.js` first, like this:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["tf.min.js", "background.js"]
  }
}
```

The scripts are loaded in the order you specify them and if you want to be able to use things from `tf.min.js` inside of `background.js`, `tf.min.js` has to be loaded first.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, I got this error:

tf.min.js:2 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at tf.min.js:2
    at tf.min.js:2
    at Py (tf.min.js:2)
    at tf.min.js:2
    at tf.min.js:2
    at tf.min.js:2

Comment: Turns out you might not be able to use Tensorflow in Chrome extensions because it uses `eval`. You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48047578/6662225) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#eval()_and_friends). I'd recommend you to import the unminifed `tf.js` to figure out where exactly that error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you. I have read that I can make the CSP be relaxed, e.g. allowing eval using the following policy:
  `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",`
And as I see, it works.