# Remove eval() for production code through webpack because of CSP issues

Tags: webpack, eval, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, content-security-policy

I am trying to **adhere to the CSP directives in the bundled production code**. We have a strict ContentSecurityPolicy in place which doesn't allow the **`eval()`** and its relatives like **`setTimeout(String)`**, **`setInterval(String)`**, and **`new Function(String)`**. Therefore I am trying to remove such statements through **webpack.config.js**.

I am using **webpack 4.28.0** and after seeing numerous guides online, I have tried the following in the **webpack.config.js**:

```
mode: 'production',
node: {
  global: false,
  fs: 'empty', // irrelevant for this example I think
}

// rest of code ... 

plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // This was put in place because before I got window is undefined errors
        global: 'window'
      }),

// rest of code ...
```

Also the **`devtool`** property is left unset (as per some guides I found online) even though I don't think it matters.

I am currently getting complains regarding the **`new Function(...)`** (see img below):

[image]

Here's the CSP error also:

[image]

I am not the most proficient in webpack, so in hopes of the rest of you being, I would like to ask you, is it even possible to do that through webpack? Have you stumbled upon such thing in the past and can you share some hints? Could it be Babel that's doing stuff?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: This is a 8 month old question but I just found this answer which helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100966/7771926