# Content Security Policy: cannot load Google API in Chrome extension using Webpack as bundler

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, content-security-policy

I am using Google calendar API and trying to load the calendar api js script in the background page and receiving error as content scripts

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Tried changing the manifest.json and setting the permissions and content security policy to evaluate `unsafe-eval`. I am using webpack and saw this post ([Chrome extension compiled by Webpack throws `unsafe-eval` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047150/chrome-extension-compiled-by-webpack-throws-unsafe-eval-error)) and change the webpack mode to production and added this to my webpack configuration file `devtool = 'cheap-module-eval-source-map';`
The following are the changes made to my manifest.json

```
1. "permissions": ["https://*.google.com/"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

2. "permissions": ["background"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Add `https://apis.google.com` to `content_security_policy` value.

Comment: Do you end up with multiple CSP headers? In that case all of them need to allow apis.googl.com in script-src for the script to load.

Comment: now it is showing `
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" in directive 'script-src'.`

Comment: @wOxxOm please can you explain how we can add It, getting an error
`'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.`

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil I get the same error. Have you gotten it resolved?

Comment: No one has given a solution on this yet!