# Uncaught EvalError: 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, unsafe-eval

I am creating a chrome extension in Manifest V3 because I realised that Chrome now disallows people from uploading extensions using Manifest V2. I made some changes and this is what my manifest.json looks like now.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "SpeedRead",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-128x128.png"
    },
  "icons": {
    "128": "./assets/img/icon-128x128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "css": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "styles.css",
        "icon-128x128.png"
      ],
      "matches": []
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "script-src": ["self", "unsafe-eval"],
    "object-src": "self"
 }
}
```

[image]
However, I got this error when running my chrome extension. The error seems to be coming from popup.html which is in my build folder. This issue did not occur when I was using Manifest V2. I am not sure how I should resolve this issue. I'm a newbie so help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension compiled by Webpack throws \`unsafe-eval\` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047150/chrome-extension-compiled-by-webpack-throws-unsafe-eval-error)